# h() render function in Vue returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to display icon when condition is passed and for that I'm using theme icon

###### Script Code

```
<script setup>
import { h } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps({
  itemDetail: Object
});

const passedIcon = h('i', {class: 'bx bxs-check-circle'});
const failedIcon = h('i', {class: 'bx bxs-cross-circle'});
</script>
```

###### Template Code

```
<template>
 <tr>
  <td>Zip check</td>
  <td>
   {{ props.itemDetail.status == 'pass' ? 'Passed ' + passedIcon : 'Failed ' + failedIcon }}
  </td>
 </tr>
</template>
```

But It's returning

```
Passed [object Object]

or 

Failed [object Object]
```

I had tried with h() render function but passed directly through `.innerHTML` which works fine but How can I achieve to directly call as html with h() render function in the template?

Comment: You're concatenating the component to a string resulting in `[object Object]`, instead use `<passedIcon />` and `<failedIcon /> `

Comment: @Reyno You can't do this either because passedIcon is supposed to be a comp and not vnode

Comment: I tried `<passedIcon />` and `<failedIcon />` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @KamranAllana fixed my answer to print text labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly the icon class names inside the template using conditional rendering :

```html
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  itemDetail: Object
});

</script>
<template>
 <tr>
  <td>Zip check</td>
  <td>
    <template v-if="itemDetail.status == 'pass'">
      Passed <i class="bx bxs-check-circle"/>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
       Failed <i class="bx bxs-cross-circle"/>
    </template>
  </td>
 </tr>
</template>
```

You could also use the built-in component `component` with its prop `is` bound to the icon based on the condition :

```html
<script setup>
import { h, computed } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps({
  itemDetail: Object
});

const passedIcon = h('i', { class: 'bx bxs-check-circle' }, );
const failedIcon = h('i', { class: 'bx bxs-cross-circle' }, );
const icon = computed(() => {
  return props.itemDetail.status == 'pass' ? passedIcon : failedIcon
})
</script>

<template>
  <tr>
    <td>Zip check</td>
    <td>
      {{ itemDetail.status == 'pass' ? 'Passed ' : 'Failed ' }}
      <component :is="icon" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

[DEMO](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

You could also avoid repeating the conditional statement by refactoring the vnode created by `h`:

```
const passedContent = h('span',{},['Passed',h('i', {class: 'bx bxs-check-circle'})]);
...
```

Comment: This one is the nice strategy but `<Component :is="">` takes more memory utilization I guess?

Comment: Where did you find that `<component ../>` takes more memory use?

Comment: Just asking @Boussadjra

Comment: @KamranAllana no, it doesn't have any performance issues

Answer (score 0):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Convert your functional components to functions - they are called functional for a reason:

```
<script setup>
import { h } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps({
  itemDetail: {type: Object, default: {}}
});

const passedIcon = () => h('i', {class: 'bx bxs-check-circle'});
const failedIcon = () => h('i', {class: 'bx bxs-cross-circle'});
</script>

<template>
 <tr>
  <td>Zip check</td>
  <td>
  <template v-if="itemDetail.status == 'pass'">Passed <passed-icon /></template>
   <template v-else>Failed <failed-icon /></template>
  </td>
 </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: https://play.vuejs.org/#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]

Comment: Tried this one with your code

Comment: @KamranAllana the link is broken

Comment: Oops, well I found the way with both of your answers. Thanks for your quick response.